# Is it feasible to do SQL INSERT to a CSV file?

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm writing a DB persistence layer to my application and for testing, particularly on remote systems where getting a DB set up can take time, I would like to add the option to persist to CSV.

Of course I can quite easily write a separate `class CSVDataWriter : IDataWriter` to complement my `class MSSQLDataWriter : IDataWriter` but I wondered if I can avoid this and use my exact same code to run the same SQL INSERT queries into a CSV file? I've seen mention that you can configure a datasource/connection string to provide basic functionality through CSV but I can't tell if it's going to take more more that just writing a separate CSV class.

Can this feasibly be set up so by just amending by connection config in app.config, my code will think it is writing to an SQL data source which is actually a CSV text file? If so, how?

Comment: https://github.com/morrisjdev/FileContextCore is a flatfile-provider with several available formats for entity framework - maybe that could help you?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I think if I need to add additional packages it probably becomes more trouble than it's worth. I thought I'd seen ODBC drivers could somehow do this but if not, I'll probably not bother :)

Comment: SQLCMD.EXE has a CSV option.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you looked at this ODBC driver? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.CSVODBCDriver